# Is there anyway to detect a client disconnect in Python SocketServer.TCPServer?

Tags: python, tcp, serversocket

I've tried the below code without success. Basically, I need a way to detect the client disconnection. I'd like to avoid a chatty heartbeat type system. Is there anyway to detect when the socket is no longer open (either client has disconnected or it's been broken/etc)?

```
class ThreadedTCPRequestHandler(SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        while True:
            self.data = self.rfile.readline().strip()
            if not self.data:
                print 'Client closed connection'
                break
```

I thought this would work, but it doesn't seem to (also tried with the strip() removed). Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Rather late now, and a very hacky approach, but one easy workaround at least for testing purposes is to use a timeout wrapped in a try-catch block to detect a potentially-disconnected client

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, detecting that a client has become 'silently' unavailable is not possible.  Unless the client closes the connection in a managed fashion, (ie. perfoms the FIN four-way handshake), the server will not detect a dead client unless it tries to communicate with the client and fails.